# Usar una variable dentro de una consulta de un DBLINK

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, subconsultas, jasper

Quisiera preguntarles lo siguiente, es posible usa una variable para filtrar la información que viene desde una consulta de un DBLINK?. Algo como esto:

```
SELECT *
FROM (

SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=db port=5432 host=dbhost user=dbuser password=dbpassword',
        'SELECT column_1, column_2, date_in
        FROM table t
        WHERE t.date_in >= $P{start_date}') as 
            check_table(column_1 integer, column_2 text, date_in date)
    ) as b order by checkout_number
```

Este resultado lo utilizo en un reporte que publico en JasperSoft, pero hasta ahora no he logrado la forma de utilizar el parámetro $P{start_date} sin generar un error. Por eso pensé que tal vez podría guardar ese valor que me pasan como parámetro en una variable antes de obtener los datos de la consulta interna, y luego usar esa variable como valor de filtro.

Es posible hacer algo de este estilo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si esa variable está dentro de postgres (es una columna de una tabla accesible) se puede usar `quote_literal`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM dblink('dbname=db port=5432 host=dbhost user=dbuser password=dbpassword',
            'SELECT column_1, column_2, date_in
            FROM table t
            WHERE t.date_in >= '||quote_literal(start_date)) as 
                check_table(column_1 integer, column_2 text, date_in date)
        ) as b order by checkout_number
```